# Android Webview app, uploading image not working, nothing happens when tap select photo

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, uploading

I have create an Android Webview app and it works normally, but when i tap buttons which are used to upload photo, nothing happens. I m attaching my code so you guys can help me out

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView myWebView;


private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    myWebView = new WebView(this);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        //The undocumented magic method override
        //Eclipse will swear at you if you try to put @Override here
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
            MainActivity.this.showAttachmentDialog(uploadMsg);
        }

        // For Android > 3.x
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
            MainActivity.this.showAttachmentDialog(uploadMsg);
        }

        // For Android > 4.1
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
            MainActivity.this.showAttachmentDialog(uploadMsg);
        }
    });

    this.setContentView(myWebView);

    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.droidocial.com");
}

private void showAttachmentDialog(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
    this.mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    i.setType("*/*");

    this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Choose type of attachment"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
        if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
            return;
        }
        Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
        this.mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
        this.mUploadMessage = null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
        myWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".Splashscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.official.droidocial.droidocial.MAINACTIVITY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I tried too much, but still stuck in this error, can someone tell me how can I resolve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this could help https://www.opengeeks.me/2015/08/filechooser-and-android-webview/.

```
Uri[] results = null;
String dataString = intent.getDataString();
if (dataString != null) {
    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
}
mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(results);
```

Also You need this permission to access files on device:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Shoud I put this into mainactivity?

Comment: @Syndicate the code above should be in your onAcitivtyResult.

Comment: that link is not working anymore